# INVALID_TYPE ERROR while querying using REST API

Tags: rest-api, query, httprequest

I'm trying to run a query using REST API (RestSharp).

This is my query:
[SELECT Id FROM Account]

This is my code:

```
RestClient m_Client = new RestClient("https://my_instance.salesforce.com");
string requestQuery = "/services/data/v48.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+Account";
RestRequest restApiRequest = new RestRequest(requestQuery, Method.GET);
restApiRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + m_SFToken.AccessToken);
IRestResponse<string> restApiResponse = m_Client.Execute<string>(restApiRequest);
```

I get a Bad Request error:
[{"message":"\nSELECT Id FROM Account
^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:16\nsObject type 'Account' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.","errorCode":"INVALID_TYPE"}]

This is not a custom object.
I get the same error when querying a custom object.

**But when I change the query to be: SELECT+Id+FROM+User I do get a response**

- In developer console I get responses for all queries above.
- I have tried adding "tooltip" : "/services/data/v48.0/***tooltip***/query/?q=
- There is no namespace

Any ideas why am I getting this error? or could this be fixed?

Comment: The most likely scenario is that you're logged in with a user or Connected App that doesn't have access to the object. Check your user profile permissions, and also check to see if the Connected App scope includes `api` or `full` access.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for the help.
My problem was in the profile permissions.